# No attribute error passing broadcast variable from PySpark to Java function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have a java class registered in PySpark, and Im trying to pass a Broadcast variable from PySpark to a method in this class. Like so:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(spark.sparkContext._jvm, "net.a.b.c.MyClass")
myPythonGateway = spark.sparkContext._jvm.MyClass()

with open("tests/fixtures/file.txt", "rb") as binary_file:
    data = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(binary_file.read())
    myPythonGateway.setData(data)
```

But this is throwing:

> AttributeError: 'Broadcast' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

However, if I pass the byte[] directly, without wrapping it in broadcast(), it works fine. But I need this variable to be broadcast, as it will be used repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [py4j docs](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/ac9e0e26911954a26df0884b10cd63e9b4a46e1c/py4j-web/advanced_topics.rst#converting-python-collections-to-java-collections), the above error will be thrown if you try to pass a Python collection to a method that expects a Java collection. The docs give the following solution:

> You can explicitly convert Python collections using one of the following converter located in the py4j.java_collections module: SetConverter, MapConverter, ListConverter.

An example is provided there also.

Presumably, this error is occurring when py4j tries to convert the `value` attribute of the `Broadcast` object, so converting this may fix the problem e.g.

```
converted_data = ListConverter().convert(binary_file.read(),spark.sparkContext._jvm._gateway_client)
broadcast_data = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(converted_data)
myPythonGateway.setData(broadcast_data)
```