# How to broadcast java object using pyspark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use a Java UDF in a pyspark application. My Java UDF consumes a broadcast variable

My Java class below

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;

public class TestUDF implements UDF1<String, String> {

    private Map<String, String> productMap;
    @Override
    public String call(final String someStr) throws Exception {
        return "this worked " + this.productMap.getOrDefault(someStr, "11111");
    }

    public void setBroadcastMapData(Broadcast<Map<String, String>> broadcastVarMap) {
        this.productMap = broadcastVarMap.getValue();
    }
}
```

From this stack overflow answer - [No attribute error passing broadcast variable from PySpark to Java function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731683/no-attribute-error-passing-broadcast-variable-from-pyspark-to-java-function) I figured out how to cast the python object to java object

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
from py4j.java_collections import MapConverter

java_import(spark_context._gateway.jvm,"com.test.udf.TestUDF")

func = spark_context._gateway.jvm.TestUDF()

product_map = {
    "Shoes": "SizeShoes",
    "Dresses": "SizeDresses",
    "Pants": "SizePants"
}

converted_data = MapConverter().convert(product_map, spark_context._jvm._gateway_client)
broadcast_data = spark_context.broadcast(c_data) # This line fails
func.setBroadcastMapData(broadcast_data) # Never gets to this line
```

However it is not able to serialize the java broadcast variable and I run into this error

```
An error was encountered:
Could not serialize broadcast: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o714.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```